# Jupyter Shortcut not working

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am working my code on Jupyter(Python). Normally, the shortcut to insert cell below is 'b' and for above is 'a', but when I do that search bar opens instead of insertion of cell.[image: Jupyter shortcut problem]

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Just adding a comment, hoping it will help people. So, command based on [esc] key did not work in my JupyterLab notebook. I taped the following combination [shift][d][d], then [esc] commands were operational again. I don't know why but it worked for me.

Answer (score 47):

I had this issue and it turned out that my Chrome plugin (Vimium) was intercepting keypresses before Jupyter could capture them.

In my case, I just added a rule to the plugin to disable it on my common notebook urls, like `localhost:8888`.

There are potentially other plugins that might exhibit the same behavior, so generally I'd try opening a window without any plugins activated and see if the unexpected behavior persists.

Comment: I hit this problem too just now. Removing Vimium fixed the problem

Comment: If you add a rule and leave it blank it will disable all vimium shortcuts on that domain

Answer (score 13):

Your issue is probably because of your browser settings. `b` must be set to something else or you are not on *command mode*.

**Jupyter shortcuts:**

> **Command Mode (press Esc to enable)**
>
> Enter : enter edit mode
>
> Shift-Enter : run cell, select below
>
> Ctrl-Enter : run cell
>
> Alt-Enter : run cell, insert below
>
> Y : to code
>
> M : to markdown
>
> R : to raw
>
> 1 : to heading 1
>
> 2 : to heading 2
>
> 3 : to heading 3
>
> 4 : to heading 4
>
> 5 : to heading 5
>
> 6 : to heading 6
>
> Up : select cell above
>
> K : select cell above
>
> Down : select cell below
>
> J : select cell below
>
> A : insert cell above
>
> B : insert cell below
>
> X : cut selected cell
>
> C : copy selected cell
>
> Shift-V : paste cell above
>
> V : paste cell below
>
> Z : undo last cell deletion
>
> D,D : delete selected cell
>
> Shift-M : merge cell below
>
> S : Save and Checkpoint
>
> Ctrl-S : Save and Checkpoint
>
> L : toggle line numbers
>
> O : toggle output
>
> Shift-O : toggle output scrolling
>
> Esc : close pager
>
> Q : close pager
>
> H : show keyboard shortcut help dialog
>
> I,I : interrupt kernel
>
> 0,0 : restart kernel
>
> Space : scroll down
>
> Shift-Space : scroll up
>
> Shift : ignore

---

> **Edit Mode (press Enter to enable)**
>
> Tab : code completion or indent
>
> Shift-Tab : tooltip
>
> Ctrl-] : indent
>
> Ctrl-[ : dedent
>
> Ctrl-A : select all
>
> Ctrl-Z : undo
>
> Ctrl-Shift-Z : redo
>
> Ctrl-Y : redo
>
> Ctrl-Home : go to cell start
>
> Ctrl-Up : go to cell start
>
> Ctrl-End : go to cell end
>
> Ctrl-Down : go to cell end
>
> Ctrl-Left : go one word left
>
> Ctrl-Right : go one word right
>
> Ctrl-Backspace : delete word before
>
> Ctrl-Delete : delete word after
>
> Esc : command mode
>
> Ctrl-M : command mode
>
> Shift-Enter : run cell, select below
>
> Ctrl-Enter : run cell
>
> Alt-Enter : run cell, insert below
>
> Ctrl-Shift-Subtract : split cell
>
> Ctrl-Shift-- : split cell
>
> Ctrl-S : Save and Checkpoint
>
> Up : move cursor up or previous cell
>
> Down : move cursor down or next cell
>
> Shift : ignore

Comment: 'ctrl + m' and pressing 'b' works for inserting cell below
'ctrl + m' and pressing 'a' works for inserting cell above the current position

Comment: @SijanBhandari yes.

Comment: @AniMenon no, even that is not the case. I have checked the shortcuts and they are set to a and b.

Comment: @CuriousLad Press `Esc` 2 times and retry.

Comment: @AniMenon sorry but not working either. even i don't know why it is happening

Comment: @CuriousLad . Have you tried pressing 'ctrl+m' at once and leaving those keys and press only key 'b' ?

Comment: @SijanBhandari yes, every possible scenario

Comment: Same issue here :'(

Answer (score 8):

Not quite on topic of the question text but I got here from the title of the question. If you're on **MacOS** I noticed that the frequently used `run-cells` shortcut recently (I'm using notebook v6.1.1) changed from the original (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can check/change the current keyboard mappings from the **Help** menu in Jupyter. And the keyboard mappings are shown for <kbd>a</kbd> (and <kbd>b</kbd>) under the **Insert** menu.

Comment: I'm wondering why would they do that. makes it much harder to use, since "finger memory" is all messed up, and changing in"Help Menu" doesn't work for me.

Comment: anyone know a way around this? Updating the keyboard shortcuts doesn't work.

Comment: I can't fix this either. This bypasses my Sublime key mapping where cmd+enter creates a new line below and moves my cursor there.

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution if you have Vimium installed. just add a rule to ignore B, attached [image]

Add all the shortcuts you want to work (hit esc key prior to every command):

1. shift + enter run cell, select below.
2. ctrl + enter run cell.
3. option + enter run cell, insert below.
4. A insert cell above.
5. b/B insert cell below.
6. C copy cell.
7. V paste cell.
8. D , D delete selected cell.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer: Vimium has the option to disable some mappings as shown in the image above. You do not need to uninstall or disable Vimium.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out! It has to do with a chrome extension blocking your jupyter shortcuts.  You can test this by opening http://localhost:8888/notebooks in another browser.

In my case, I'd installed a chrome extension called Vimium, which was messing everything up.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10, it was this application - [Easy Windows Switcher](https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/) that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, and I google it. I found answer from [here](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding/issues/38). You just update your jupyter through `pip install -U jupyter`. Maybe it works.(if you install jupyter from anaconda,you can use `conda update jupyter` command.)

Answer (score 0):

try to open the jupyter-lab from cmd, use this command :

```
jupyter notebook
```

it will start working normal and when you finished using these keys will help you to stop the application :

```
control + c
```

Answer (score 0):

By switching to Jupyter lab (upper right option inside the Jupyter notebook), I was able to get the commands working. That doesn't solve the issue inside the notebook, but can get you unblocked

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupyter Lab instead of Notebook, Shortcut works fine there. I prefer use  Lab while you dont get the solution.