# Does anyone know why Jupyter notebook shortcuts are not working?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I try to use the shortcuts in a Jupyter notebook, some of them do not work. I have looked at the list of shortcuts but when I actually try to trigger them nothing happens.

I have tried command, control, command + m ...

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have the same issue? What can I do about it?

I am using macOS.

Comment: Are you going into 'command mode'... Have a look at this tutorial. https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/back-to-basics-jupyter-notebooks-dfcdc19c54bc

Comment: Are you using Safari or another browser, do you have any extensions installed? Does the following question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195536/jupyter-shortcut-not-working