# Is there a JupyterLab shortcut for re-indenting code?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there an equivalent of `Ctrl+I` from Rstudio in JupyterLab for automatically indenting lines of code?

I was checking the extensions jupyterlab_code_formatter but didn't work out for me. I could not get the toolbar activated.

Comment: Related: [Jupyter shortcut not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195536/jupyter-shortcut-not-working/38195812#38195812)

Comment: Are you talking about typing in the JupyterLab code cell? It should auto-indent as you type after things like lines defining functions or starting off for loops. Hence the 'auto' in it. Or are you asking for a shortcut to force indenting how you want later & therefore your use of "auto" terminology in the title & post is not consistent with what you seek?  It is probably system-specific but `Command + ]` works on Mac. (Ctrl+I is listed as reindenting lines [here for RSTudio](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-the-RStudio-IDE), nothing 'auto-indenting'.)

Comment: <continued> Some are listed [here](https://defkey.com/codemirror-shortcuts) for systems. For completeness sake, there has been some flux in what is used as shortcuts as the versions of CodeMirror used have evolved, too. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/comment-out-code-block-in-jupyterlab4/19520?u=fomightez). Under 'Settings' > 'Advanced Settings Editor' > 'Keyboard Shortcuts' you can see the ones that don't come from CodeMirror.

Comment: I think the said 'auto' works in the Jupyter Notebook (file.ipynb) cell but not while working on an R script file (file.R). Like in R studio, it would be nice to have Ctrl+I feature that adjusts the indents in case if you have messed things up while writing the codes. And Ok! Reindenting might be the proper terminology.